# Node, phantomjs & converting html to pdf: element dimensions ignored?

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I am wanting to generate a PDF from an HTML document, where the HTML document has elements specified with dimensions in cm. The idea is that an element or image is specified to fit in the page as specified. The issue is I can't get the dimensions to be respected.

This is the test HTML I am working with:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>test case</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div style="width: 21cm; height: 27cm; border: solid 1px black;">This should be within page bounds!?</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Trying with the NodeJS module 'phantomjs-pdf' (0.1.2), I used the following code:

```
var pdf = require('phantomjs-pdf');

var options = {
    "html" : "./test-data/document.html",
};

pdf.convert(options, function(result) {

    /* Using a buffer and callback */
    result.toBuffer(function(returnedBuffer) {});

    /* Using a readable stream */
    var stream = result.toStream();

    /* Using the temp file path */
    var tmpPath = result.getTmpPath();

    /* Using the file writer and callback */
    result.toFile("out.pdf", function() {});
});
```

The output document is 21cm x 29.71.cm (US Letter).

I have tried another package 'html-pdf', which also seems to to be PhantomJS based and get the same behaviour, suggesting the issue may be PhantomJS related?

Any suggestions?

I am open to using an alternative package for going from HTML to PDF, on the condition the element dimensions are respected. This is because I will be using an image as the background (PNG or SVG, depending on support), which represents an expected document template and then will be putting HTML elements with a given section of the page, based on an absolute position within an element.

I am using NodeJS 6.7.0, MacOS X 10.12 and I have PhantomJS 2.0.0 installed via MacPorts.

Comment: Is the div not inside the body like your sample shows?

Comment: @KevinBrown Just a copy/paste issue in the question. Fixed the HTML example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on PhantomJS after discovering https://github.com/fraserxu/electron-pdf.  So far it has exceeded expecations.  Because Electron runs Chromium the [printToPDF](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-contents/#contentsprinttopdfoptions-callback) functionality works pretty much as you'd expect.  You can `npm install electron-pdf` and use the CLI to evaluate it for your app.  Since you want Letter size add `-p Letter` and maybe set the margins to none.

In either case, I found that the (browser) window size in pixels needed to match the PDF size.  For Letter this would be (8.5" * 96) by (11" * 96)  96 is the standard pixel per inch ratio for HTML.  If you want to work in cm use that ratio.